# Implementation layer in Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

There is **DAO**, **service**, **DTO**, **controller**, **entity** layer in java. I got in DTO we create database table as entity is an **POJO** class. Controller is where we write web service call using jersey or some spring controller (RequestMapping...).

But I'm not getting about service layer and DAO layer. In DAO layer we write about accessing the database. And in service layer we write implementation about the web services. So, do we use dao object in service layer. I want to know the brief idea about this service layer and DAO layer.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have the right idea.

The DAO is the piece that actually connects to the database and saves/retrieves data, the service layer contains the surrounding business logic. DAO is typically called from a service layer.

Good practice is to put as little business logic as possible in the DAO and to leave that to the service layer instead.

Answer (score 0):

These are different logical entities:

- The DAO layer's purpose of existence is only to provide a connection with DB (that.s why DAO = data access object) and execute SQL commands into it (ex. using Hibernate).
- The service layer provides a logic between the raw data sent from a database and a client. In the service, you call the DAO layer to provide the objects. On the service level, you usually execute the business related rules, validations, authorization etc.

The main idea is to not let the endpoints (`@Controller`, `@RestController`) manipulate with the database layer directly.

Answer (score 0):

> DAO is a data access object, is an object that provides an abstract
>   interface to database. The DAO provides some specific data operations
>   without exposing details of the database

But DAO doesn't have specific business logic or shouldn't have it, if you have more business logic to apply besides CRUD operations, you need a service layer too.

> This DAO can do CRUD operations, it can Create, Retreive, Updata,
>   Delete from our table.

The interface of our DAO should be like this:

```
public interface UserDao {
    User getUser();
    Set<User> getAllUsers();
    User getUserByUserNameAndPassword();
    boolean insertUser();
    boolean updateUser();
    boolean deleteUser();
}
```

The service layer will take the business logic if you need to verify access before performing CRUD operations or logging, these are some examples.

In the architecture, Controller -> service layer -> DAO -> entities...
Controller has a reference to service layer and service has a reference to DAO

More information on this links:
https://dzone.com/articles/building-simple-data-access-layer-using-jdbc
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object